# PHP Sort an array by 2nd letter after last slash in string

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have a script that pulls all of the images out of a directory and in a few subdirectories, puts them in an array and echoes them out, also pulling the artist name from the corresponding html file and displaying that under the image. What I need to do though, is to sort them by artist last name before I echo them out. Right now the artist name begins with first initial. Basically I need to write a sort that sorts by the 2nd character after the 'last' occurrence of a '/' since some of the image pathnames have 2 '/'s. This is what I have for code so far:

```
<?php
include('../simplehtmldom_1_5/simple_html_dom.php');
$n = 0;
$dirname = "artists/";
$dirs = array_filter(glob($dirname . '*'), 'is_dir');

foreach ($dirs as $dir)
{
    $images2[] = $dir . "/" . str_replace($dirname, "", $dir ) . ".jpg";    
}

$images = glob($dirname ."*.jpg");

$images = array_unique($images);
$images = array_merge($images, $images2);

$numCols = 7;
$skip=0;
echo "<table class='artists'>\n";
echo "\t<tr>\n";

foreach( $images as $i => $image )
{   

    if(1 === preg_match('~[0-9]~', $image)){
    $image = next($images); 
    }
    if ( $i != 0 && $i++ % $numCols == 0 )
        {
            echo "\t</tr>\n\t<tr>\n";
        }
        $imgstr = substr($image, 0, strpos($image, '.'));
        $namestr = str_replace($dirname, "", $imgstr);      
        $htmlfile = $dirname . $namestr . "home.html";
         $htmlcontent = @file_get_contents($htmlfile);
        echo '<td><a href="../index.php?page=artists&artist=' . $namestr . '" target="_parent"><img src="' . $image . '"  /><br />' . get_page_title($htmlfile) . '</a></td>';
    }
echo "\t</tr>\n";
echo '</table>';
?>
</div>   
</body>
</html> 
<?php 
function get_page_title($htmlfile) {
  $html = file_get_html($htmlfile);
  $title = $html->find('title', 0)->plaintext;
  return $title;
} 
?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: you'd attract more answers by dumping a sample array that you want sorted, everybody would want an idea on how the array looks like, or the paths

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if I got it, but is it something like this: https://3v4l.org/fioGJ ?

Comment: what if the artist's name is _JK Rowling_ or something?

Comment: here's the end of the array....artists/rrose.jpg [73] => artists/rshetterly.jpg [74] => artists/rsylmor.jpg [75] => artists/schaisson.jpg [76] => artists/sloughridge.jpg [77] => artists/swilder.jpg [78] => artists/swilder2.jpg [79] => artists/tgaines.jpg [80] => artists/thigbee.jpg [81] => artists/wungerer.jpg [82] => artists/bmoulton/bmoulton.jpg [83] => artists/fschrock/fschrock.jpg [84] => artists/ntryon/ntryon.jpg [85] => artists/smost/smost.jpg [86] => artists/tginn/tginn.jpg [87] => artists/uskozak/uskozak.jpg

Comment: Ghost, I would use jrowling. Rizier, thanks alot for the code. I'm getting an error though: Undefined offset: 2 in C:\wamp\www\myprojects\UMVA\WEB\includes\inc_artists.php on line 44. Line 44 is:   return strcmp($ma[1], $ma[2]); Thanks.

Comment: I changed the way I am trying to do this. I have an indexed array and I'm trying to sort by the 2nd character of the index. The array is created with the following code:                                                                  foreach( $images as $i => $image )
{
 if(1 === preg_match('~[0-9]~', $image)){
 $image = next($images); 
 } 
 
 $artist = str_replace($dirname, "", substr($image, 0, strpos($image, '.')));
 if(strstr($artist, '/')){
    $artist = substr($artist, 0, strpos($artist, "/"));
 }
 $artists[$artist] = $image;
 
}